# Need help on how to improve accuracy Tesseract Android OCR to read meter more accurately

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract, tess-two

I have been working in a meter reading project. I try to use the Tesseract for android to get 5 digit of the meter readout but having difficulties on the accuracy.

Meter Image(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y8cc.png)

It does not correctly translate the number on the meter reading. I had tried to change the PSM to 7, but still not accurate.

Here's the output:
[Tess-Two Output Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gf8rT.jpg)

It seems that to use the Tesseract you need to crop the image clean leaving only the number (no noise) ? and the number had to be in perfect shape?

In my app, I use a manual cropping method (using rectangle that can be resize using finger), but its very difficult and troublesome as I need to make sure only the number that is inside the rectangular.

Is there any way to increase the accuracy of the recognition?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.